# Change pixel colour based on binary mask opencv

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, mask

I have a binary mask that highlights the part of my image I want to change. I've seen examples online that use a mask to change pixel colours in an image like so:

```
img[mask>0]=(0,0,255,255)
```

However instead of a solid pixel colour, I want to change these pixels to a fraction of their original colour. For example, I want to do something like this:

```
img[mask>0]=(img * 0.8 + (0,0,255,255) * 0.2)
```

When I do this I get the error

> TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'

How can I change these pixel values to be a fraction of their original value?

Comment: i assume `img` is your image object , and `img * 0.8 ` multiplying image object  by a float ( or anything else) doesn't look right.

Comment: yes img is my 4 channel image (in the form of a numpy array). How would I apply a mask but modify the pixels relative to the current pixel value?

Comment: I've used `apply` which could apply a function to a selection of cells, but I don't remember if that was pandas or numpy.  It was a long time ago for me.

Comment: `img = img * 0.8 * (mask > 0 ) + ((mask<=0) * 0.2)[...,None] * [0,0,255,255]`